# Eigenvalues of K + I*$\sigma$ given that K is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I recently got stuck on proving the following theorem which I need for another question:

Let K be a NxN diagonalizable matrix, I the NxN idendity matrix and $\sigma$ a real number. Prove that

$\lambda$(K + I*$\sigma$) = $\lambda$(K) + $\sigma$, where $\lambda$ denotes all the eigenvalues of the corresponding matrix.

The only thing I could come up with is that you can write K as PD$^{-1}$P, where P has the eigenvectors as columns and D has the eigenvalues on its diagonal. I believe you can somehow use this identity to prove it, but so far I couldn't come up with anything.

Also, I was given the following NxN matrix B:

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\&&1&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

Apologies for the poor use of syntax, but for clarification this is supposed to be a square matrix of size N with zeros on its diagonal, and the value 1 as its near-diagonal entries. Its eigenvalues and eigenvectors are:

$\lambda_{k}$ = 2cos($\pi$k$\triangle$x), x$_{k}$ = \begin{bmatrix}sin(\pi k\triangle x)\\sin(2\pi k\triangle x)\\\vdots\\sin(N\pi k\triangle x)\end{bmatrix}. Is there someway for me to use this information to gain the eigenvalues of another matrix that is identical to B, except it has the value -1 as its near-diagonal entries?

Thank you for your time, if something isn't clear please let me know.

Comment: "another matrix that is identical to B, except it has the value -1 as its near-diagonal entries", isn't it exactly $-B$?

Comment: @Guangliang Oh yeah right, so the eigenvalues are just -1 times the original eigenvalues then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K$ has an orthonormal set of eigenvectors $v_i$. Then $( K + \sigma I) v_i = (\lambda_i+\sigma)v_i$. So every eigenvector of $K$ is also an eigenvector of $K+\sigma I$. Since $v_i$ is orthonormal, you're done because $K+\sigma I$ could not possibly have any other eigenvectors. Equivalently, as you wrote that $K=PDP^T$, then $K+\sigma I = P(D+\sigma I)P^T$ and you can read off the eigenvalues.

For your second question, aren't you saying your new matrix is just $-B$? Hence its eigenvalues are negatives of those of $B$.